# Euler's formula about graphs embedded in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, surfaces, connectedness, geometric-topology

> State and prove Euler's formula about graphs embedded into $\mathbb{R^2}$

I know that if we suppose $ G  $ is a finite connected graph drawn on the surface of a sphere $  S^2 $. Then the complement  $  S^2 -G $ consists of  $ F=2-\chi(G)  $ `faces,' connected regions homeomorphic to open discs.

But is the statement for $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is Euler's polyhedral formula. It states that for every convex polyhedron with $V$ vertices (corners), $E$ edges and $F$ faces the formula $V-E+F=2$ holds.

The same statement holds for planar graphs. So the statement for $\mathbb R^2$ is that the formula holds if your graph is a planar graph.